# How to restore antique dressform?

Tags: tool-selection, technique-selection, restoration

I bought this antique-looking dressform for my partner, but I can tell it's seen better days. It says Adjustoform on the neck, which I expect is the brand. I want to repair it as best as possible, but I don't know the first thing about dressforms, nor antique repair. What I think I might need to do:

1. Steam the covering to clean it.
2. Apply some sort of contact adhesive over the undercovering and re-lay the covering so that it lays flat.
3. find a new foot for the stand.

Are there any pitfalls I should watch out for, or other things I need to do?

[image]